# Find mongoose model by model name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to set up different models with the same schema for look up purposes, but I am running into an error when I try to find the model by the name given to it. I get the error "Schema hasn't been registered for model "model1", but the model is clearly shown in the database.
The following is the code for setting up the model:

```
const model = mongoose.model(modelname, Schema)
var doc = new model({var1, var2, var3});
doc.save().then((resp) => {
  return res.status(200).json(resp);
})
```

The following is the code for accessing the model again in a different route:

```
var model = mongoose.model(modelname, Schema);
```

The issue is that the model name is a variable, so I will never know the exact model being accessed

edit:
schema

```
const Schema = new Mongoose.Schema({
    var1: String,
    var2: String,
    var3: String
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you share your schema? Especially if you have any `ref`s in it

Comment: there are no refs, it just has 3 strings in it

Answer (score 1):

**Not Correct, Want Update**
I think, when u use `var model = mongoose.model(modelname, Schema);` mongoose will register this to database so it cause error duplicate with same **modelname**.
And if  want to have more model to one Schema, I think u use different **modelname**
If u want to connect to one model, u can use `exports` and `require` to get

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
export default User;
// other file
import UserModel from "./userModel.js";
```

Comment: Hello! I appreciate the response. I have also tried const model = mongoose.model(modelname);, which throws the same error. I cannot use exports or require as the routes are on two different servers, and on top of that the model name does change based on the request body.

Comment: thanks,now i have clearly your question, i will update my response if i have answer.